# Why two seperataly doped semiconductors cannot be joined to form a junction?

Tags: semiconductors, electricity, pn-junction

My textbook says that when a slab of P-type semiconductor and another slab of N-type semiconductor are joined, they cannot form a junction because no matter however smooth the surface is, there will always be some irregularities present in it and hence continuous contact will not be possible.

Why is this continuous contact necessary? Maybe it is necessary for electrons to jump from one slab to another. But in case of two metallic slabs, we can make electricity flow in it. How is this happening?

In other words, how are electrons trapped at the interface of a semiconductor but are not at the interface of a metal?

Comment: It's tempting to think of "point contact" diodes/transistors as a counterexample, but generally there the actual junction is not at the point of contact, but rather between the bulk semiconductor and a small region where some of the metal from the contact wire has diffused into it as a dopant under the influcence of current made to flow during manufacture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the interface of semiconductors, the silicon structure ends abruptly causing unwanted effect. Silicon atoms will not be able to make the usual 4 covalent bonds, causing electrons to be "trapped" more easily. These trapped states are annoying and will have several undesired effects. For all practical purposes, that destroys the diode characteristic.

The whole idea of a PN junction depends on the flow of holes and electrons and how they balance out. However, in metals, there's only one game in town: electrons... Free electrons, and lots of it! Having a few irregularities at a metal contact is not that big of a deal if you have so many free charge carriers floating around. 
If you sandwich the metal between the junctions, however, you remove any "semiconductor interaction" as you force holes and electrons indiscriminately through that sea of electrons. Holes are immediately recombined, electrons get lost in the sea.

That being said, some rectifying behavior can still happen for a metal-semiconductor junction (as is the case for a schottky diode). But it will not be the same curve as a PN junction.

Comment: So, irregularities in metal contact prevent the two slabs to form a junction because the carrier concentration is very low. Have I understood this correctly? Also, how electrons are trapped at the interface of a semiconductor and not of a metal is the thing I am trying to understand.

Comment: No just the nature of a metal destroys the PN junction. If you put two separate slabs without metal together, the surface irregularities will also break operation.

Comment: Sorry for poor wording, I was not trying to ask the behavior of a diode with metal in between. I want to explain in my school's oral examination, how electrons do not cross the surface irregularities of two differently doped semiconductors, while in case of two metallic slabs put over one other, electricity can flow from one slab to another.

Comment: Metals do not trap electrons because they have more electrons in the valence band than they want. Ie. They want to get rid of that 1 or 2 extra electrons, causing a big sea of electrons that are just moving freely. This is different than silicon that wants 4 extra electrons to form a covalent bond with. So if the silicon doesn't find 4 neighboring silicon atoms, then it will try to steal some freely moving electrons, trapping them.